# How to get and observe ref to element from a v-for?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

All answers that seem to tackle a similar issue relate to Vue 2 or simply don't give the expected results. Even what's described in [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#watching-template-refs) doesn't work, because if I log the value of the ref I just see an empty object.

I have a template like so:

```html
<template>
  <post-content v-for="post in posts" :post-data="post" :key="post.id" ref="lastPost" />
</template>
```

The content of the PostContent component is unimportant, imagine it as a div displaying whatever's into `post.content`.

In the script I fetch `posts` from an API, and I'd like to have the last loaded post in the reference `lastPost`, so that I can access its `HTMLElement` (I need it for stuff, but here I just try to log it).

```js
// This uses composition API with <script setup> syntax

const posts = ref<{id: number, content: string}[]>([])

getPostsFromApi()
  .then((thePost: {id: number, content: string}) => posts.value.push(thePost))

const lastPost = ref<typeof PostContent>()

watch(lastPost, () => nextTick(() => console.log(lastPost.value)), {flush: "post"})
```

However, this results in the log being a simple empty object `{}`.

- I need to be able to access the HTMLElement itself once it has loaded.
- I need to watch the reference for changes, so that I can get the element every time I add posts.
- I only need the last post at any given time, I don't care about previous ones. I will only add posts one at a time. This is why I'm not using an array as a ref.

Why is an empty object being logged instead of what, according to the docs, should be expected? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike SFCs with a regular `<script>` block, `<script setup>` components are **closed by default** -- i.e. variables inside the `<script setup>` scope are not exposed to the parent unless explicitly exposed via [`defineExpose()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose). An empty object in the logged template ref implies you haven't exposed any properties.

To expose the root element of `PostContent`, use a template ref in the component, and expose the `ref` (e.g., named "`$el`") with `defineExpose()`:

```html
// PostContent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const $el = ref()
defineExpose({ $el })
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="$el">...</div>
</template>
```

As an aside, `watch()` with `{ flush: 'post' }` can be simplified to [`watchPostEffect()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watchposteffect):

```js
watch(lastPost, () => nextTick(() => console.log(lastPost.value.$el)), {flush: "post"})

// OR more simply:
watchPostEffect(() => console.log(lastPost.value.$el))
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-root-el-in-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPostContent.vue)